# Как генерировать точно уникальное значение?

Tags: django

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    unique_id = ?
    user.username = f'{self.cleaned_data['first_name']}-{unique_id}'
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Как получить id, которого точно не существует в базе данных?

Может есть способ использовать id, который база данных генерирует сама?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: Сгенерировать любой id и проверить, не существует ли он в базе; если существует - сгенерировать другой id

Comment: «Может есть способ использовать id, который база данных генерирует сама?» — да, используйте `user.id` на здоровье сразу после `user.save()`

Answer (score 0):

Уникальный идентификатор в Django представлен как `pk` (primary key).
Поле, помеченной им, всегда будет уникальным и Вы просто не сможете создать новый экземпляр, если он будет с существующим значением `pk`.

Если не пометить ни одно поле, то Django автоматически создаст поле `id` и пометит его как `pk` поле. Это довольно хороший вариант, он используется в стандартной модели `User` Django.

Чтобы получить `pk` экземпляра модели `User`, обратитесь к нему как к атрибуту:

```py
user.id
```